# Functions and variable assignment Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
a=[8,2,15,6,1]
a = a.sort()
print a
```

Why does it print `None`? Can you elaborate on all functions?

Comment: don't assign a.sort() to a. Just sort it and print a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort()` and `sorted()` are different:

- `sort()` sorts the list in-place and returns `None`.
- `sorted()` creates a new list and returns it.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) for further details.